# Sony Vaio PCG-6H8P doesn't exist

Tags: drivers, sony-vaio

I've been handed a Sony Vaio about 3 years old, with the model number PCG-6H8P, and I need the drivers for it.

According to Sony, the laptop doesn't exist. According to Google, the laptop doesn't exist. It was purchased in Australia, and I can guarantee that the laptop exists.

Any ideas on where I can get more information for it? I've been doing this for **years** and I've never run across anything like it.

<sub>(p.s. I've already tried all my favourite driver-updater software, and all they could recognise was the wifi driver)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this also goes by the model number [**VGN-S58GP**](http://vaio-online.sony.com/prod_info/vgn-s58gp_b/index.html).  You should be able to find drivers for that model without any problems and they should work just fine.

[image]

Comment: http://www.sony.com.au/support/download/product/vgn-s58gp/modelfirst :-)

Comment: Looks like they're going to work! Thanks! How on earth did you know about the compatible product numbers though?

Comment: Wohoo - they all worked :D You made my week - and it's only 10am on Sunday!

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar experiences, except with a laptop brought back from Japan. If you need drivers for the devices I would search for the hardware IDs on Google and get the driver packages from there.

You may also want to contact Sony Support.

Comment: I already tried that :( I've wasted hours on this already - most of the hardware is sony-specific without generic drivers