# Sony VAIO PCG-9RBL Drivers

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, drivers

I need to find the windows drivers for a Sony VAIO PCG-9RBL. Similar to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/111379/sony-vaio-pcg-6h8p-doesnt-exist) the PCG-9RBL doesn't exist. So what else do they call it? When you type in PCG-9RBL at Sony'e eSupport it brings up:

- PCGK23
- PCGK23Q
- PCGK25
- PCGK27
- PCGK32

Any idea?

Comment: Speaking of eSupport... Is it just me or did eMachine ruin the eNAME thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PCG-9RBL has a subrange, usually PCG-9RBL K23, PCG-9RBL K25, PCG-9RBL K27, etc. The sony site says it already, you need to be more specific. Check your laptop if there's K23, K23Q, K25, K27 or K32 somewhere on it. (Usually on the bottom somewhere)

Also check http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/support-info.pl?info_id=264

Comment: D'oh... is says PCG-k27 on the front LCD bezel. Silly me for looking on the tags on the bottom.

Comment: Well good you found it after all ;)